# How to check each typed word without click btn

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea. And foreach word that users type in the textarea i want to check that typed word as they type.

How can i do that best with javascript/angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need an event listener on key presses, if you're using Jquery there's a $.keydown() function, then just listen for space bar presses, something like:

```
var lastWord = '';

$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {

   if (e.keydown == 32) {
       //do something with the last word typed
       lastWord = ''
   } else {
       var content = $(this).value
       lastWord.concat(content.slice(0,-1)) //last letter in textarea
   }
})
```